# How to handle different user types in auth0 authentication?

Tags: express, authentication, auth0

I am currently developing several different 'apps/web apps', they all talk to a central API.

There are 3 different types of users that will use these apps: 
Internal Staff - Admin dashboard type application 
Partners - Apps for partners to interact with our systems 
Customers - Customer facing apps

The API is built with nodejs/express, and I am looking to use auth0 to handle user authentication and authorization.

Am I correct in thinking I should use a different tenant within auth0 for each user type?

If so, can each separate tenant have different scope access to a single API that is shared among all 3 tenants?

Comment: You could use sperate applications in a single-tenant, and set roles (via rule) to users based on the client id of the app.

we can get [`context.clientID`](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/references/context-object) and base on the client id we can [set roles to users](https://auth0.com/rules/roles-creation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking I should use a different tenant within auth0 for each user type?

I would recommend using role based access control (RBAC) for this instead of spreading it out across multiple tenants.

- https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/rbac